# Where is the routing history of a web page stored?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router, we use a hook `useNavigate()` to programmatically navigate to various pages of our website.

For example, our website has 3 components `Home, New, Recommended`.
Now, let's say I navigated from `Home` to `New` and then from `New` to `Recommended`.
Now, if I call the hook `navigate(-1)`, it will navigate me to `New` section.

My question is, where is this history stored in the browser?
And, where can I see this history in chromes inspect developer tools?

Comment: check for stored routing history using third party npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-redux

Answer (score 0):

React Router uses the `window.history` api under the hood, which is standardized among browsers.

It is a global object, that you can access in the browser's console.

Read more about the history object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)

[image]

> My question is, where is this history stored in the browser?

Most probably somewhere in the browser's memory and it depends on the browser's internal implementation. But all browsers expose a part of this history through the `history` object to the webpage.

> And, where can I see this history in chromes inspect developer tools?

It is not possible to see the visited paths. That would expose the whole browser history of the user to the webpage. Browsers won't allow that for obvious security and data protection reasons. But you could store the visited subpages of your page in the `history` objects state and access those paths according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for this.
But for example, If I navigate from localhost:3000/ to localhost:3000/new.
And Then from localhost:3000/new to localhost:3000/recommended.
So, Where is this localhost:3000/new for back() and localhost:3000/ for go(-2) stored in that entire History object?
I can see the length of history object increasing when I navigate to various components, but I cannot specifically see the link localhost:3000/new or localhost:3000/recommended in that object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not possible unless you store it somewhere on your own. See my edited answer.